# Difference between AuthenticationManagerBuilder and HttpSecurity.authenticationProvider

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

To provide a custom authentication provider in spring boot, do I need both of the following? and what is their difference?

[AuthenticationManagerBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html)

[HttpSecurity.authenticationProvider(...)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authenticationProvider-org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider-)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Autowired
  private MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
  }

  // --------------- OR/AND ? ----------------
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
      .authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider)
      // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use one of the two options.  Internally, http.authenticationProvider is just making a call to AuthenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider.